# Navigation Drawer Best Practices?

Tags: android

The app is already made and working.  I have a navigation drawer layout.  It has the hamburger, the "up" button that can replace it, and of course the back key on the phone.  My main question is how to correlate the up button and the back key -- for example should they both always lead to the same page?  Or should the up key always go to the home page?  Should it not be used at all?  Should the hamburger only be used to open the drawer?  The app is working and these will be easy changes to make, but i don't know what people are used to and expect.